# How to Get App Reviews from Appstore in .NET Core

Tags: ios, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to get customer reviews for the app from appstore and then turn it into Excel file . I want to do it in Asp.NET Core How can i do that. I saw many apple articles like "List All Customer Reviews for an App" and "List All Customer Reviews for an App Store Version" , but none of them helped. Can anyone please help me and guide me how can i perform this. This is my office project and **i will be Fire if i failed to perform it**

I recently found this link which returns the app reviews of app store but it doesn't return review which does not contain text.

"https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=123*******/sortBy=mostRecent/page=1/xml"

Can anyone guide me further and complete?

I saw many apple articles like "List All Customer Reviews for an App" and "List All Customer Reviews for an App Store Version" , but none of them helped. Can anyone please help me and guide me how can i perform this. This is my office project and **i will be Fire if i failed to perform it**

I recently found this link which returns the app reviews of app store but it doesn't return review which does not contain text.

"https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=123*******/sortBy=mostRecent/page=1/xml"

Can anyone guide me further and complete?

Comment: Why the domain is `https://itunes.apple.com` ? Could you kindly check this official doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/list_all_customer_reviews_for_an_app